# Duplicates quotes method hash join

Tags: ruby, hash, escaping, quotes

I have a hash with those elements

```
@ratings = {"PG"=>"1", "PG-13"=>"1"}
```

I select only the keys and separate it with `,`

```
keys = @ratings.keys.join("','")
```

I want to use them in a select in query:

```
Movies.where(:rating => [keys])
```

But it only works with a simple value, because when there are more, the quotes are duplicated:

```
SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."rating" IN ('PG'',''PG-13')
```

Why does it duplicate the quote?

Comment: What is `@ratings`? Does it have anything to do with `ratings`?

Comment: If what you have is really `'PG'',''PG-13'`, then that is equivalent to `"PG,PG-13"`.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `join` you are passing a string to your where clause and the layer that generates the SQL string is sanitizing your input. I assume you are using `ActiveRecord`? If so, then simply pass the array directly.

```
Movies.where(:rating => @ratings.keys)
```